# Splitting string based on delimiter Alteryx

Tags: alteryx

I have a string like this

> Abc\defg\hijk\lmn

My requirement is to get last part of the above string based on delimiter ****

I tried text to column tool and it needs more filtering and formulas.. I really believe there should be an easier method.

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, one easy approach is to reverse the entire string, then take the first instance up to the given delimiter, then reverse that substring to achieve the desired result. Caveat: original string shouldn't be ridiculously huge.

Answer (score 2):

Following up the comment from @johnjps111:

> one easy approach is to reverse the entire string, then take the first
>   instance up to the given delimiter, then reverse that substring to
>   achieve the desired result. Caveat: original string shouldn't be
>   ridiculously huge

Here is one-step method to get your requested output, using Formula

> Input: Abc\defg\hijk\lmn

```
ReverseString(Left(ReverseString([Input Text]),FindString(ReverseString([Input Text]), "\")))
```

> Output : lmn

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought about using RegEx?

The following Regular Expression `.*\\(.*)` will return the part of the string after the last backslash.

[Click here](https://regexr.com/44urc) to read more about how this works or to adapt it for any particular constraints you have.

Use the [RegEx Tool](https://help.alteryx.com/2018.3/RegEx.htm) to implement this approach in Alteryx.

Click below to see some screenshots of how this will look in practice:

[RegEx Tool configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHB9r.png)

[Example workflow and results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SuEW.png)